# Session.close() doesn't free resources on GPU using tensorflow.

Tags: session, memory, gpu, tensorflow

I would like to perform pretraining of neural network using autoencoders implemented in TensorFlow.

1. I am able to run whole network. (Using TF or Keras). the whole graph fits into GPU memory so that's fine.
2. Problem occurs when I create more graphs (autoencoders). GPU run out of memory very quickly. Right now I have example where building second level autoencoder causes GPU out of mem. exception.

So what is happening:

I have implementation of autoencoders which has session as it's attribute, so :

```
self.session = tf.Session()
```

and implements method

```
destroy()
```

where

```
self.session.close()
```

is called.

When stacking autoencoders, some instances of Session are needed and that's when I got the problem.

What am I missing? isn't .close() enough?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1727